# ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial' from partially initialized module 'serial' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

Hello i want to use the pyserial modul but i have some difficulties with this error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial' from partially initialized module 'serial' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Graf\Desktop\Experimente\Python\serial.py)
```

This is my code

```
import serial

from serial import Serial

s = serial.Serial('COM9', 9600)
```

But whats a little bit strange when i type each of the lines of code in the python consol it works. But I cant use the code as script. I allready tried to run the code in Atom, the script(.py file) and the file with CMD but nothing of them worked.
I use Python 3.9.1, Win 10, 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that your file is called `serial.py`:

```
C:\Users\Graf\Desktop\Experimente\Python\serial.py
```

Python will check your current working directory first when importing, and if you have a file called `serial.py` in there, it will attempt to import it before any external libraries. A file importing itself obviously doesn't make sense in the vast majority of cases though.

Just rename your file to something else.

Comment: Thank you so much I didnt think that this could be a problem :)

Comment: @Jonas No problem. To avoid issues like this, it's a good idea to be conscious of the names of files you may want to import, and to avoid those names. Using longer, more descriptive names (like `serial_test.py`, or `serial_driver.py`) can make this issue far less common as well.

Comment: Yes I renamed it to serial_test.py I only named it serial so that it is easy for me to find